# XML Node with text and nodes together

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML document looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <node>some Text
        <subnode>other text</subnode>
    </node>
</root>
```

Now I want to get the content of node without the subnode- in my example only "some Text".
I tried `XmlNode.InnerText` (gives me the whole text with subnodes) and `XmlNode.Value` (gives me null)

Now I wonder, if this is valid XML at all and if yes how to get it in C#?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, in part. And Eldar shown me how to read this in c#. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a valid XML. You can use Linq to XML to retrieve the text. `Some Text` is notated as `TextNode` you can verify it with `NodeType` property.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xmlText = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8""?>
<root>
    <node> some Text
        <subnode> other text </subnode>
    </node>
</root>";
        var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlText);
        var textNode = (xml.FirstNode as XElement).FirstNode;
Console.WriteLine(textNode.ToString());
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uxPXd8)